# Intento actualizar pip pero tira error ValueError: Unable to find resource t32.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib

Tags: python, windows, pip

intento actualizar PIP, porque me dice que la versión es vieja, pero me tira el siguiente error:

> ERROR: Exception:  Traceback (most recent call last):    File
> "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py",
> line 188, in main
> status = self.run(options, args)    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\req_command.py",
> line 185, in wrapper
> return func(self, options, args)    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
> line 398, in run
> installed = install_given_reqs(    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\req_init.py",
> line 67, in install_given_reqs
> requirement.install(    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\req\req_install.py",
> line 804, in install
> install_wheel(    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\install\wheel.py",
> line 622, in install_wheel
> install_unpacked_wheel(    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\install\wheel.py",
> line 550, in install_unpacked_wheel
> generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)    File
> "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
> line 415, in make_multiple
> filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\install\wheel.py",
> line 285, in make
> return super(PipScriptMaker, self).make(specification, options)    File
> "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
> line 404, in make
> self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
> line 304, in _make_script
> self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)    File
> "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
> line 239, in _write_script
> launcher = self._get_launcher('t')    File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\scripts.py",
> line 383, in _get_launcher
> raise ValueError(msg)
>
> ValueError: Unable to find resource t32.exe in package
> pip._vendor.distlib

intenté hacerlo mediante python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip (como sugiere) y python -m pip install --upgrade pip

En ambas tira el mismo error.
tengo windows 10 y python 3.8

Comment: Hola Iván, parece que tienes el propio paquete pip "roto", intenta desinstalar pip con `python -m pip unistalll setuptools wheel pip`, luego descarga [get_pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) y ejecutalo con `python get_pip.py`, obviamente con CMD en el directorio donde lo descargues o pasando la ruta completa.

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo error. Como dijo FJSevilla desinstale pip y lo volvi a instalar con get_pip y se me solucionó. La unica cosa que hice diferente fue desinstalar pip con "pip uninstall pip".